# TypeError: _co.class.function is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular 6 and I'm very new to it.
My object is to define a class function and then call it from the connected component, but I get the following error.

```
TypeError: _co.installation.selectOrDeselect is not a function
```

**installation.ts**

```
export class Installation {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    img: string;
    version: number;
    agents: number;
    ip: string;
    connection: string;
    selection:  string;

    selectOrDeselect() {
        if (this.selection == 'not-selected') {
            this.selection = 'selected';
        } else {
            this.selection = 'not-selected';
        }
    }
}
```

**installations.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Installation } from '../installation';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-installations',
    templateUrl: './installations.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./installations.component.css'],
})
export class InstallationsComponent implements OnInit {
    installation: Installation = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Master',
        img: 'assets/logo.jpg',
        version: 7,
        agents: 95,
        ip: '192.168.0.1',
        connection: 'not-connected',
        selection: 'not-selected'
    };    

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

**installations.component.html**

```
<div class=""class="col-2 installationContainer {{installation.selection}} {{ installation.connection  }}" (click)="installation.selectOrDeselect()">
    <h3>{{ installation.name }}</h3>
    <img src="{{ installation.img  }}">
    <div><label>versione: </label>{{ installation.version }}</div>
    <div><label>agenti: </label>{{ installation.agents  }}</div>
    <div><label>ip: </label>{{ installation.ip  }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`installation: Installation = {...}`

Here you are just specifying the object type for compile-time type check by the typescript compiler. The type `Installation` will not be taken at runtime.. just your object. You need to do:

```
installation = new Installation();
```

To have the method available.
You may also need to define a constructor for your `Installation` class which takes in all the properties and sets it.

```
export class Installation {

    constructor(
        public id: number;
        public name: string;
        public img: string;
        public version: number;
        public agents: number;
        public ip: string;
        public connection: string;
        public selection:  string;
    ){}

    selectOrDeselect() {
        if (this.selection == 'not-selected') {
            this.selection = 'selected';
        } else {
            this.selection = 'not-selected';
        }
    }
}
```

And initialization:

```
installation = new Installation(1,'Master','assets/logo.jpg',7,95,'192.168.0.1','not-connected','not-selected');
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but after reading more about Angular I came to the conclusion that my question was plain wrong. I was trying to achieve a result not in the the way I was supposed to.